# Call the "grunt serve" command from java project

Tags: java, angularjs, gruntjs

I have a java project that preform some algorithm and in the end of that program I want it to initiate a web app. The web app is been written in nodejs and angularjs and I'm using Grunt as a task manager.

The only thing I would like is that the java program would execute the command "Grunt serve" from the web app project directory.

When using **Runtime.getRuntime().exec** command its simply doesn't do anything.

I also tried to write some shell script code which execute **Grunt serve** and to run it from the java code but it also didn't outcome nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the grunt is installed in global, and other packages are installed too. Then you also need to set working dir as the root of angular app. If there is still some error, you can redirect the std out and std error to some place and check the log.